# Model classes don't show up in Add View dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I asp.net mvc my model classes won't show up in the Add View dialog, so that VS automatically can generate CRUD views for them.

I have my Model classes (Linq-to-SQL) in a separate project (but in the same solution) than my asp.net MVC project.

Only stuff from the Elmah and Autofac namespace shows up in the list!

Comment: Maybe the stuff on this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771579/asp-net-mvc-problem-of-creating-strong-typed-view/771683#771683

Comment: Yes, i had'nt compiled the project since i'd added the model classes to the controller.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you create an instance of the model classes in the controller methods? They won't get seen by the VS view wizards bits unless you do.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply required to build the project after the model has been created and before the you try adding the view.